# Deep data structure match & replace first

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I'm trying to figure out an idiomatic, performant, and/or highly functional way to do the following:

I have a sequence of maps that looks like this:

```
({:_id "abc" :related ({:id "123"} {:id "234"})}
 {:_id "bcd" :related ({:id "345"} {:id "456"})}
 {:_id "cde" :related ({:id "234"} {:id "345"})})
```

The `:id` fields can be assumed to be unique within any one `:_id`.

In addition, I have two sets:

- `ids` like `("234" "345")` and
- `substitutes` like `({:id "111"} {:id "222"})`

Note that the fact that substitutes only has `:id` in this example doesn't mean it can be reduced to a collection of ids. This is a simplified version of a problem and the real data has other key/value pairs in the map that have to come along.

I need to return a new sequence that is the same as the original but with the values from `substitutes` replacing the *first* occurrence of the matching id from `ids` in the `:related` collections of all of the items. So what the final collection should look like is:

```
({:_id "abc" :related ({:id "123"} {:id "111"})}
 {:_id "bcd" :related ({:id "222"} {:id "456"})}
 {:_id "cde" :related ({:id "234"} {:id "345"})})
```

I'm sure I could eventually code up something that involves nesting maps and conditionals (thinking in iterative terms about loops of loops) but that feels to me like I'm not thinking functionally or cleverly enough given the tools I might have available, either in clojure.core or extensions like `match` or `walk` (if those are even the right libraries to be looking at).

Also, it feels like it would be much easier without the requirement to limit it to a particular strategy (namely, subbing on the *first* match only, ignoring others), but that's a requirement. And ideally, a solution would be adaptable to a different strategy down the line (e.g. a single, but randomly positioned match). The one invariant to strategy is that each id/sub pair should used only once. So:

*Replace one, and one only, occurrence of a `:related` value whose `:id` matches a value from `ids` with the corresponding value from `substitutes`, where the one occurrence is the first (or nth or rand-nth...) occurrence.*

Comment: your example data is unparsable as either a map or a sequence, did you mean this: `({:_id "abc" :related ({:id "123"} {:id "234"})}
 {:_id "bcd" :related ({:id "345"} {:id "456"})}
 {:_id "bcd" :related ({:id "234"} {:id "345"})})`

Answer (score 0):

```
(def id-mapping (zipmap ids 
                        (map :id substitutes)))
;; id-mapping -> {"345" "222", "234" "111"}

(clojure.walk/prewalk-replace id-mapping original)
```

Comment: Not sure if 'id-mapping' is the mapping exactly the same as you mentioned. I think you meant replace "345" with "222", replace "234" with "111".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the collection is called `results`:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(defn modify-related
  [results id sub]
  (loop [loc (z/down (z/seq-zip results))
         done? false]
    (if (= done? true)
      (z/root loc)
      (let [change? (->> loc z/node :_id (= id))]
        (recur (z/next (cond change?
                             (z/edit loc (fn [_] identity sub))
                             :else loc))
               change?)))))

(defn modify-results
  [results id sub]
  (loop [loc   (z/down (z/seq-zip results))
         done? false]
    (if (= done? true)
      (z/root loc)
      (let [related (->> loc z/node :related)
            change? (->> related (map :_id) set (#(contains? % id)))]
        (recur (z/next (cond change?
                             (z/edit loc #(assoc % :related (modify-related related id sub)))
                             :else loc))
               change?)))))

(defn sub-for-first
  [results ids substitutes]
  (let [subs (zipmap ids substitutes)]
    (reduce-kv modify-results results subs)))
```